# Django - model class with non-persistent attribute that should be refreshed on each call

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

My User class looks like :

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, SafeDeleteModel, PermissionsMixin):
    UNKNOWN = 'Unknown'

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    default_organization = models.ForeignKey(to='Organization', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
                                             related_name='default_organization', blank=True)

    organizations = models.ManyToManyField(to='Organization', through='UserOrganizationMembership',
                                           related_name='users', blank=True)
```

So a user can be a part of multiple organisations. However, each time he logs in, he must log in through ONE organisation.
Now I have two kinds of orgs present - internal, client
I have some telemetry setup for my application and the idea is that i want to not send any telemetry for internal orgs.
I want to create an attribute in the /users api that returns this flag (flag depends on both the user and the account he logs in through).

My view class looks like this:

```
class UsersViewSet(UpdateModelMixin,
                   ListModelMixin,
                   GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        #self.request.user.is_telemetry_enabled =should_send_event(self.request.user, self.request.tenant.is_internal)
        context.update({"request": self.request})

        return context

    def get_permissions(self):
        permission_classes = [IsStaff] if self.action in ('list',) else [CanEditUser]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

What I've looked at :

1. adding a field in model class and setting it in the `get_serializer_context`. Doesn't work because adding a field in model makes it a class variable, not per instance. second, it still didn't show up in the /users response.
2. setting this as a property in models/users.py. Doesn't work because for setting a property the only argument allowed is `self` and my flag depends on `self` as well as which account self is logged in through. This information is present in the req context for me.

tldr :
I want my GET `/users` (mapped to UsersViewSet) endpoint to return an additional param that is calculated every time the endpoint is hit. Currently, it returns the model picked directly from the db.

How do I achieve this? I'm fairly new to django/python

Comment: *The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: I just edited it with the requirement.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the calculated field in "UserDetailSerializer" class where you can calculate the value from where ever you want, such as session.